# Unable to fetch geolocation in Chrome 47

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am able to fetch user's geolocation from firefox and older versions of Chrome (Chrome 45) I used.
In Chrome 47, I am not able to get the result.

What could be the possible reason? Anything wrong with my code? here's the code.

```
var cord= '';
if (navigator.geolocation) 
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;

      alert( lat+','+lng);

    }, function(error) {
        alert( 'error');
    });
} 
    else 
{
  alert('else of navigator.geolocation ');

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/zskdmkwb/)

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be working for me in Chrome 47. As a sanity check, are you sure you didn't previously disable geolocation? Check in the address bar to right. I believe you can click on the target there and clear your old settings.

Comment: Nopes. I didn't. Even if I denied earlier, I can change that setting from chrome://settings/content @akosel

Answer (score 1):

The underlying API hasn't changed and the code example you have here also works well. It does suggest that it might have been rejected in the past.

To do some debugging in Chrome on the client, you can use the [permissions API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/permissions-api-for-the-web?hl=en) to query if the page has access to the API - if it returns `denied` then the user has blocked access.  For example.

```
navigator.permissions.query({name: 'geolocation'}).then(function(e) {
  alert(e.state);
  e.onchange = function() {
    alert(this.state);
  };
});
```

If it says 'prompt' it means that the user has never accepted the permission before or they dismissed the prompt on a previous page load.  The two other states are explicit granted and rejected states where the user made a definite choice.  If you see either of these two, specifically `denied` then your issue is that the user or you have rejected the prompt previously.

Lastly, and this is a warning and heads-up. You need to ensure that you are running on `https` - we will be changing the requirement for access to the geolocation API to only be available over https.  We expect this change to land in the coming months.

If this all fails, then it could be that there is an issue in Chrome.  One such bug is in [Chrome Dev Tools](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=542923) where if you toggle Emulate Geolocation and turn it off again then you get a couple of errors.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about. I tested this from a Chrome 47 browser i;ve never used and no one has ever granted/denied location permission in it. No alert is being shown there. But in older browsers, alert box is being shown. I have removed everything under location coming under chrome://settings/content. @Kinlan

Comment: I went through that article you wrote for Geolocation. But it doesn't return any coordinates for latest version of Chrome. Correct me if I am wrong. @Kinlan